# How to cd into a directory with blanks?

Tags: bash, directory, cd

I have a directory called "foo bar baz blob". How can I

```
$ cd "foo bar baz blob"
```

I have tried with quoting (" and ') and with escaping the blanks (\ ). It does not work. Tab-completion does not work either.

I also have to issue commands with filename arguments that contain spaces. How do I do that? Even MidnightCommander (mc) fails in doing this.

**EDIT**

Over one year later, I finally found the source of my problem. I have overloaded the builtin cd with a function that automatically lists the files of the changed directory:

```
$ type cd
cd ist eine Funktion.
cd () 
{ 
    if builtin cd $1; then
        ls;
    fi
}

$ cd Interner\ Speicher/
bash: cd: Interner: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

$ builtin cd Interner\ Speicher/

$ pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C018%5D/Interner Speicher

$ ls
Alarms   DCIM      Movies  Notifications  Podcasts   SmsContactsBackup
Android  Download  Music   Pictures   Ringtones
```

The solution is easy: I just have to put double quotes around the $1:

```
if builtin cd "$1"; then
```

Ooof. Thank you.

Comment: Quoting or escaping should work. Is the `foo bar baz blob` directory within your current directory? Check with `ls` - if not you will need to add the absolute or relative path to the directory name.

Comment: Is the `foo bar baz blob` folder in the home directory? By default, terminal opens 'in' the home directory, so the command would not work otherwise.This is how it should be escaped in terminal:   `cd foo\ bar\ baz\ blob/`.

Comment: do `ls` in the directory and edit it in your question so we can see exactly what characters we are dealing with.

Comment: Perhaps did you get these files from a mac? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

- Escape the spaces using a backslash character
- Wrap the directory name in double-quotes (`""`)
- Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion

**Creating the directory:**

```
user@pc:~/testfolder$ ls -l
total 0
user@pc:~/testfolder$ mkdir "foo bar baz blob"
user@pc:~/testfolder$ ls
foo bar baz blob
```

**Method 1:**

```
user@pc:~/testfolder$ cd foo\ bar\ baz\ blob/
user@pc:~/testfolder/foo bar baz blob$ echo "This works"
This works
```

**Method 2:**

```
user@pc:~/testfolder$ cd "foo bar baz blob"/
user@pc:~/testfolder/foo bar baz blob$ echo "This works, too"
This works, too
```

**Method 3:**

```
user@pc:~/testfolder$ cd foo<TAB><ENTER>
```

Based on your comment on the other answer: for accessing the file named, the escaping needs to be done as follows:

```
Eric\ Burdon\ -\ Starportrait\ -\ CD\ 1\ \(flac\).cue foo\ bar\ baz\ blob/
```

However, using <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion makes this process easier and avoids you having to escape the spaces manually.

Comment: method 3 would be my method 1 :D [tab] seems to work better (it will also resolve unprintable chars and will also do different enconding correctly)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I changed the directory's name into "EricBurdonStarportrait" with the Thunar file manager, so that the problem left was to use the filenames as arguments on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I just created the same folder, in /home/abed, used tab completion, and it worked.  See image below.  If the folder was created at a different location, you'll have to navigate to that location before you can CD into your folder.

[image]

That's also OK.  See image

[image]

Comment: What wrong with the answer?

Comment: OK, Hmmm. Then I think the problem is that there is a "-" in the directory name, e.g., "The Rolling Stones - Sticky Fingers - 1971". Escaping by "\-" does not work.

Comment: Then the problem is in a "(", which is also in the filename. The file I want to process is "Eric Burdon - Starportrait - CD 1 (flac).cue". Here, escaping \( and \) does not work: `shntool [split]: error: need exactly one file to process`

Comment: @ubuplex is a file or a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Quote your filename with single quotes.

```bash
cd 'foo bar baz literal string'
```

In the shell, nothing is interpreted inside single quotes so you should be safe from having unusual characters.