# Install .tar from USB Drive

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive

I don't have enough space on my disk to both have the .tar and install it. So I moved it to my USB. I'm very new to Ubuntu and am struggling to run a couple of commands.

Not sure if this is necessary. But I ran these steps:

```
ssh -Y <uio_username>@laser.uio.no
tar -cvf matlab.tar /opt/app-sync/matlab
logout

scp <uio_username>@laser.uio.no:~/matlab.tar ~/matlab
tar -xvf matlab.tar
```

the last step:

```
tar -xvf matlab.tar
```

worked, but I ran out space. So I copied the file "matlab.tar" to my USB.

From here I'd like to run:

```
tar -xvf matlab.tar
```

I've figured out that the file is now located at "/media/removable/USB Drive"

I hope do something like

```
cd /media/removale/USB Drive
```

and then run

```
tar -xvf matlab.tar
```

But that yields "No such file or directory"

How do I solve this?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: See [How to cd into a directory with blanks?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/404043/how-to-cd-into-a-directory-with-blanks). However *probably* what you should be doing is staying in the directory where you want to untar the archive, and using `tar -xvf '/media/removable/USB Drive/matlab.tar'`.

Comment: @steeldriver I wish I saw your commetn before! I got it to work, but it is untaring in the USB right now, haha. I will try your method once this stops :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

Spaces in file and directory names in Ubuntu can cause problems for the shell, like bash (zsh,ash,sh,fish etc.)

Try :

```
cd "/media/removable/USB Drive"
```

You can also install Midnight Commander, which is a great file manager for text console, and does not have these problems with spaces.

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Midnight Commander can extract zip and tar files by pressing the  key on such a file, and then use the copy (F5) command inside mc.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mc

Comment: I used the Quotation marks, and now things are happening in the terminal :)

Comment: im happy for you , because it works now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract it to your home directory instead of the USB stick, then instead of changing directories to the USB stick, you just want to run `tar` from your home directory, and ask it to extract the file from the usb stick:

```
tar -xvf "/media/removable/USB Drive/matlab.tar"
```

Or alternatively:

```
tar -xvf /media/removable/USB\ Drive/matlab.tar
```

Note that the space normally separates two different arguments so it needs to either be enclosed in quotes, or prefixed with a backslash to prevent that.  Typing /media/removable/US and hitting TAB will auto complete the name for you, with the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to the directory containing the `tar` file you want to extract/install:

```
cd /media/removable/USB Drive
```

Then, run this command to extract the file:

```
sudo tar -zxvf /media/removable/USB Drive/matlab.tar
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked without the -z though. And I had to add " " on the path.

Comment: There's no point in specifying the full path to the file when you already cd'd to the directory it is in.